# Sound of gnawing a bone

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, onomatopoeia

I want the audience to be sure what was *crunching* was torn apart deer bones, not the crunch of the joint capsules of the old wolf, whenever it bent its knees to take another bite. What word or phrase to use for predator gnawing bones of its prey. Referring to the bone breaking sounds?

*I could hear the sound of ____ bones behind the tree. The wolf had its feast.*

**Edit.** Does the word *crunch* unambiguously paint the **poor** deer? Or may it evoke a parallel image of an **old** wolf?

Comment: I expect this comes down to opinion, that is, what sound you'd expect the bones to make and then what onomatopoeic expression you choose. Breaking, creaking, crackling, crashing, snapping, clacking, crunching - there are a lot of valid options.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin As stated here in accepted answer `cracking` may refer to the sound of a joint of an old man. I am looking for a word that associates with `breaking`: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72828/what-do-you-call-the-crunching-sound-from-bone-joints

Answer (score 2):

In his book *The Plague Dogs*, Richard Adams used the word...

[scrrunshin'](https://books.google.com.gt/books?id=S-uFCgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=plague%20dogs%20skrunch&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj59aei3KXjAhVx1lkKHVyQDBsQ6AEIMDAB#v=snippet&q=spat&f=false)

> The tod cracked a small bone and spat it out. ***'Scrrunshin'*** bait's the bonniest'

...I thought he had made that up, but it may have come from..

***scrunch***

> to make the noise produced by hard things being pressed together, or to press hard things together so that they make a noise:

[Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scrunch)